# How to sort users in a group?

Tags: linux, sorting

I have a problem regarding sorting users in a group. I searched around the net and found this:

```
getent group <groupname>
```

So I've tried using that code into this

```
getent group MyMembers | sort
```

the output I've got is just listing the users in a group without it sorted. Like

```
MyMembers : zat,bat,aky
```

Comment: `sort` sorts lines, it doesn't sort the values within the same line. You need to extract the list of usernames from the line, split them at the commas, and sort that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a Python one-liner like this:

```
python -c "import grp; print(','.join(sorted(grp.getgrnam('MyMembers')[3])))"
```

where `','` is a delimeter for resulting string, and `MyMembers` is a name of an existing group.

Comment: @Yves sure, if you have Python installed in your system. Just create shell file with each statement on a separate line:
    `#!/bin/bash
    group=$1
    python -c "import grp; print(','.join(sorted(grp.getgrnam('${group}')[3])))"`

Make it executable with `chmod +x file.sh` or something like that. And use this way: `./file.sh MyMembers`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can accomplish the same goal with just awk and sed:

```
grep ^MyMembers /etc/group | awk -F: '{print $4}' | tr , "\n" | sort | tr "\n" , | sed 's@,$@\n@'
```

This command `grep`s for a group name in `/etc/group` file, then stips an unordered string of comma-separated users with `awk`, then converts a string into a list with `tr`, sorts it with `sort`, constructs a string with `tr` again, and then removes comma after the last item in the string and appends a newline with `sed`.